# Not able to deploy to SQL Server using DacPac

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am not able to deploy a dacpac to SQL Server 2016. There is no issue with username and password.

Error says 'Could not deploy package. Unable to connect to master or target server 'xxxx'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'xxxx'.

SQL server version is shown below.

[image]

Visual studio Version - 2015 Community Version.
Visual Studio SSDT Version - 14.X

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a generic error, normally for, couldn't connect - check the server, port, user and password are correct - one is probably wrong!

Comment: I tried connecting with user, there are no issues in connecting. :( and the user has admin privileges.

Comment: Have you tried SqlPackage.exe as a workaround? It lets you specify the precise connection string to use.

Comment: Can you post the step by step of what you're trying to do?

Comment: If it is Azure SQL, this error message means firewall issue on Azure side. Addind IP address to the firewall list solves the problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while deploying dacpac from VS 2019 to database 2019 via Azure CD pipeline, error is:                                                         Unable to connect to master or target server 'ActionDB'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'ActionDB'.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your SSDT version (SQLPackage.exe) at least that high of a version as your SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your .dacpac publish profile (xml). Ensure there is no information conflicting between what you are passing in as the username, password, connection string, etc. at runtime and what is in the xml file.